# Break loop by keyboard input in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a problem with breaking out of a loop by pressing a key.

I googled around and found *msvcrt module* but it did not solve my problem.

Here is my code.

```
while True:
    """some code"""
    if *keyboard_input: space* == True:
        break
```

I know it's a easy question but I just can't find the right module to import.

Thanks!

Comment: A continuous loop? Or one that will prompt the user and allow an option such as "quit?" You cannot stop a continuous loop with a keyboard interrupt without the interrupt killing the whole program.

Comment: This is marked as a duplicate of a question that has nothing to do with breaking out of a loop. This is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a try/except that intercepts `KeyboardInterrupt`:

```
while True:
    try:
        # some code
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print 'All done'
        # If you actually want the program to exit
        raise
```

Now you can break out of the loop using CTRL-C. If you want the program to keep running, don't include the `raise` statement on the final line.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
while True:
    strIn = raw_input("Enter text: ");
    if strIn == '\n':
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

This loop will run continuously (and print what you type) until you type enter or space+enter.

Basically, you won't be able to break directly on a space.

```
while True:
    s = raw_input(">>")
    if len(s) <= 1:
        break
    print s
```

Comment: I think you meant `if len(s) >= 1: break`